# .net maui tabbed page with toolbar

Tags: c#, .net, maui, toolbar, tabbedpage

I am migrating from xamarin to maui.

Mobile dev.

Working on a tabbed page, issue is the toolbar is not displaying.  Code below:

...

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="xxx_mobile.Views.MainPageCus"
            Title="MainPageCus"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Top"
            BarBackgroundColor="BurlyWood">

    <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
        <!-- Add toolbar items here -->
        <ToolbarItem Text="Refresh" IconImageSource="refresh.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Clicked="RefreshToolbarItem_Clicked" />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Search" IconImageSource="search.png" Priority="1" Order="Primary" Clicked="SearchToolbarItem_Clicked" />
    </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <!-- Define your tab pages here -->
        <NavigationPage Title="Sale Alerts">
            <!-- Content for Sale Alerts page -->
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="Settings">
            <!-- Content for Settings page -->
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>

</TabbedPage>
```

...

Thx for any suggestions!

Comment: See sample code https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/8.0/Navigation/TabbedPage

Comment: Thanks mate! I will go check it out and get back to you. Cheers!

Comment: I have reproduced your problem. The toolbar does not appear in maui. What is the effect of this interface in xamarin? Can you provide relevant code and screenshots?